# Can I avoid the casting to T for this case?

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a function with the following structure:

```
public class TestOrder {

    enum Status {
        CANCELLED,
        EXECUTED
    }
    
    static class Data {
        Status status;        
    }

    private  <T extends Order> void process(List<Data> dataList, List<T> currentUpdates) {
    List<T> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Data d: dataList) {
        Order order = createOrder(d);
        if(order != null) {
            orders.add((T) order); // <- warning "Unchecked cast Order to T
        }
    }

    // processing
    currentUpdates.clear();
    currentUpdates.addAll(orders);
}

    private Order createOrder(Data data) {
        if(data.status == Status.EXECUTED) {
            // processing
            return new ExecutedOrder();  // implements of Order
        }
        if(data.status == Status.CANCELLED) {
            // processing
            return new CancelledOrder();  // implements of Order
        }

        return null;
    }
}



public interface Order {
}

public class CancelledOrder implements Order {
}

public class ExecutedOrder implements Order {
}
```

Is there a way to avoid that warning? The actual object is always a subtype of `Order` so I was wondering if either I could avoid that warning or there is problem I am overlooking.

Example of calling the method (trivial for clarity):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ExecutedOrder> executedOrders = new ArrayList<>();
        process(getDataList(), executedOrders);
    }

    private static List<Data> getDataList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: can you edit your question with some code that compiles please?

Comment: @Eugene: Just to be clear, the code now compiles ok and works. I was just wondering if that warning in the IDE can be avoided. Unless I misuderstood your point

Comment: right it compiles for you, but we don't have all those classes

Comment: but I understand the question overall, still. Your cast is an upcast to an instance that is for sure a `T`, so you can suppress that warning. as far as I see it, the cast is safe

Comment: the only question is, why do you need `<T extends Order>`...

Comment: @Eugene: Updated post

Comment: @Eugene: without that I can not add to `orders`

Comment: I dont get it why can't you create `List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: @Eugene: got you, my bad, I'll clarify in the post

Comment: @Eugene: Updated post

Comment: @Eugene: Updated the post. Will always be called with the subtypes

Comment: @HenryTwist: That is a good point, but the code is guaranteed that the `data` and the list passed as arguments are consistent. I.e. all the `data` in the list are for the exact same type of orders

Comment: @HenryTwist right, saw your answer now that clarifies that in a way that makes that comment obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to avoid the warning whilst your code is in its current form. Consider this simplified scenario:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<ExecutedOrder> executedOrders = new ArrayList<>();
    process(executedOrders);
    
    ExecutedOrder executedOrder = executedOrders.get(0);
}

private static <T extends Order> void process(List<T> currentUpdates) {
    
    currentUpdates.add((T) createOrder());
}

private static Order createOrder() {

    return new CancelledOrder();
}
```

Here, there will be a `ClassCastException` thrown when accessing elements of your list. So the reason the compiler is telling you that the cast is unsafe, is because **it is**.

Although you mentioned in the comments that your `Data` arguments would guarantee the correct orders being added to the list, the compiler has no way to verify this. This isn't necessarily a problem, unsafe casts exist in a great many places, but you have to be aware that what you're doing is fundamentally unsafe.

---

I think that [shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611252/10082297) gives the best alternative, so it might be worth rethinking your approach to something similar.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to offer an ideal solution based on sample code, but given what you've provided, it might be worth refactoring `Data` and `Status` to be type-aware:

```
public class TestOrder {

    static abstract class Status<T extends Order> {
        public static final Status<CancelledOrder> CANCELLED = new Status<>() {
            @Override
            public CancelledOrder createOrder() {
                return new CancelledOrder();
            }
        };

        public static final Status<ExecutedOrder> EXECUTED = new Status<>() {
            @Override
            public ExecutedOrder createOrder() {
                return new ExecutedOrder();
            }
        };

        public abstract T createOrder();
    }
    
    static class Data<T extends Order> {
        Status<T> status;        
    }

    private <T extends Order> void process(List<Data<T>> dataList, List<T> currentUpdates) {
        List<T> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Data d: dataList) {
            T order = d.status.createOrder();
            if(order != null) {
                orders.add(order);
            }
        }
    
        // processing
        currentUpdates.clear();
        currentUpdates.addAll(orders);
    }

}
```

Comment: oh, this is lovely!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the object is always a subtype of `Order` I don't see the requirement of having `List<T extends Order>` in the first place when you could have `List<Order>`.

You are losing informations about a type by using a `Order createOrder` method and then you want it back. This is an approach which makes no sense if there's not a specific requirement.

Comment: I updated the post. You are right. I omitted an important aspect. I am passing a collection that is of any of the subtypes that is updated in the method

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, if you wish to "fly" away the cast:

```
private <T extends Order> void process(
  List<Data> dataList,  
  Class<T> orderType,
  List<T> currentUpdates
) {
 List<T> orders = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Data d: dataList) {
   T order = orderType.cast(createOrder(d)); // check are no longer required
   if (order != null) {
     orders.add(order); 
   }
}
```

But then again, the `List<T>` is more than problematic here: without the class (and therefore the cast), you could add a `CancelledOrder` in a `List<ExecutedOrder>` and this would fail when you access it.

I would personally stick to `List<Order>` and remove the generic `<T>` as it does not make sense.

Especially if you need to pass the type (using a class in such case works fine in some case, not all case):

```
   List<ExecutedOrder> currentUpdates = ...;
   process(dataList, ExecutedOrder.class, currentUpdates);
```

You should perhaps see why you are trying to use a `List<ExecutedOrder>` or `List<CancelledOrder>` in the first place.